# XML record count attribute or element

Tags: xml, xsd

Though I know a little about XML and XML Schema I haven't used it in ages and have never been particularly competent in its use.
Therefore a little help with the following would be really appreciated.

We currently receive delimited data files and would like to switch to XML files validated by an XML Schema.
The current delimited file contains a trailer record that includes a record count.

e.g.: `TRL0000155`

In the XML version, should this record count be included as an attribute of the main `<data_file>` element

```
 <data_file record_count="155">
    <record>
       record XML...
    </record>
    <record>
       record XML...
    </record>
    ...
 </data_file>
```

or as a child element of `<data_file>`

```
<data_file>
   <record_count>155</record_count>
   <record>
      record XML...
   </record>
   <record>
      record XML...
   </record>
   ...
<data_file>
```

or perhaps I am going about it all wrong and you could give me a tip on the correct method for replacing the record count entirely.

I do recognise the difference between elements and attributes but in this case I am hoping it's an issue that many have come across before and can offer a good explaination of why one is the preferred solution.

FWIW I am leaning more towards the attribute solution as the count is metadata about the `<data_file>` element but am happy to follow more expert instruction.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `<record>` element for each record, there's *technically* no need for the record count to be explicit. You can still have it, of course, for example if it helps performance. But on the other hand, it introduces the issue that it has to be kept consistent with the number of `<record>` elements.

If you do decide to store the record count, both of your approaches (attribute and element) are ok. The main difference is that when you (*if* you) build the string content of the file, attributes are ignored, while the text nodes in the elements are not. So the count would show up in the second case but not in the first.

If you can apply XPath to the XML file, determining the record cound is easy; that would just be `count(/data_file/record)`. In that case there's really no need to store the value explicitly.

Comment: The belt and braces record count is to ensure that what the sender thinks they've sent matched with what they have actually sent (record-wise). Any reason why one method would be preferable over the other?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. And as stated above, you can use either an attribute or an element for the record count.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes or elements... often you'll find they're completely interchangeable. A major difference is that elements can repeat, while only one attribute with that qualified name may appear on an element.

Semantically, I prefer using attributes when you want to say something **about** an element or structure. The name itself says it: it's an *attribute* of the containing element. Since you intend to say something about your data_file, namely the number of records, using an attribute makes a lot of sense.

Other than that, here's the remaining qualifications I use when trying to make a decision:

- Is the file going to be read by humans or manually edited, like might be the case with (X)HTML? If that's the case and there's few attributes, it's okay. But if you start getting a lot of attributes the legibility suffers since a pretty-print works better with nested elements.
- Are there namespaces involved? Quite often, schemas tend to leave attribute names unqualified, which might lead to confusion or errors. Also, qualified attributes tend to end up looking messy.
- Is there a chance the attribute value becomes anything less than a singular value, meaning it requires structure or metadata of its own? If you feel two or more attributes are related, it might be best to turn them into a separate element-based structure.